# How do I copy code from my computer into x3270 emulator?

Tags: zos, 3270, tso

I'm using x3270 on Ubuntu 16.04. The zOS does not have a good editor and having to write a lot of code and fixing it is a pain.

I want to write code on my computer and copy it into x3270 window.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I know it's not what you originally asked, but I wanted to comment that you can use NFS between Linux and z/OS quite effectively. This enables you to truly share code across z/OS and other platforms, and on the Linux side, you can even keep your code in sync using GitHub, CVS, etc. Vastly more productive than any solution involving copying code back and forth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**x3270** is a blocked based terminal interface and can be used.  The approach would be to cut and paste code.  Since you mentioned z/OS I assume you are using the **TSO** and **ISPF**.  **ISPF Edit** (Option 2 by default) allows for a Text Edit Command (`TE`) so you can cut and paste larger blocks of text.

[image]

When you press enter you will see.  You can then position the cursor and paste the text.

[image]

Sorry, I just had some assembler source handy but as you can see you can paste a large block of code.  Its cumbersome though.

[image]

Personally, this is more of a stop gap measure for edits of limited size.  There are better solutions.

I personally use **VSCode** on my local machine.  There is a plugin for VSCode from an open source project called [Zowe](https://zowe.org) that provides a plugin for VSCode in the VSCode marketplace [Visual code Extension for Zowe](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zowe.vscode-extension-for-zowe).  This is extension allows for editing code from z/OS on your local system (I use a MacBook Pro) and facilitates the file transfer for you.  This is my preferred option.  It does require that z/OSMF is installed and configured.  You'll need to check that setup on your system.

The final option is to use `SFTP` to transfer the file.  `SFTP` will allow transfer to `MVS` and `USS` file systems and provides an ASCII to EBCDIC conversion as well.

`SCP` will only transfer files to a USS based filesystem and is an option if that fits your needs.

Comment: This is what I am looking for. I am doing the Master the Mainframe challenge so the SFTP doesn't appear to work, but TE works fine.

Comment: TE works for me, but it always put the first 4 letters of the next line to the end of previous line. Is there documentation on TE?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.f54em00/ltext.htm

Comment: I think it's because of the space.

Comment: As a solution somwhere between copy/paste and "proper" FTP it might be worth to check whether transferring the files via IND$FILE might be a possibility - it is supported by x3270, so the only question would be if it is supported by the mainframe-environment.

Comment: If the MtM servers are using a standard ADCD image, good ol' FTP should be available.